# Getting ERROR :Unable to clear or re-assign the library DATA1 because it is still in use in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

Here is the code I'm running and I'm not sure why I'm getting that ERROR.

```
options symbolgen mlogic;
libname lib11 '/home/userid';

%macro SFTPLoop(ds);
   %global numobs;
   %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(&ds));
   %if &dsid %then %do;
      %let NumObs= %sysfunc(AttrN(&dsid,NObs));
      %If &NumObs>0 %THEN %DO;
         %do %while (%sysfunc(fetch(&dsid)) = 0);  

         %end;
      %end;
      %else %put ERROR:Data set &dset has 0 rows in it.;
      %let rc = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));
   %end;
   %else %put ERROR:open for data set &dset failed - %sysfunc(sysmsg()).;
%mend SFTPLoop;
%SFTPLoop(lib1.data);
```

16         libname lib1 '/home/userid';

ERROR: Unable to clear or re-assign the library LIB1 because it is still in use.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.

Comment: You code works fine for me.  I suspect you have a data set open in a viewer from that library or something else in your SAS session has a hold of a table in it.

Comment: Is that library by any chance linked to an autocall macro library or similar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try running it in a fresh session.  Also ensure if you have it open in a viewer then it is closed.  Ensure no other users or processes are using it.

Sometimes code will error at some point and prevent the `close()` statement from running.  When this happens it is necessary to run the `close()` manually. While developing sometimes it is convenient just to clear any file handles you have open.

You can use a macro like the one below to do so:

```
%macro close_all_dsid;
  %local i rc;
  %do i=1 %to 1000;
    %let rc=%sysfunc(close(&i));
  %end;
%mend;
%close_all_dsid;
```

**EDIT :**  I also noticed that you left the 'meat' out of your code.  If you are calling some other macros between the `open()` and `close()` statements it is possible you are overwriting your value of `dsid` as you are not declaring your macro variables as local.  I'd suggest you at least declare the following at a minimum:

```
%local dsid rc;
```

Another explanation is that it's possible that at some point you ran multiple `open()` statements without running a corresponding `close()` each time.  If you accidentally ran 2 `open()` statements in a row, on the first occurrence the value of `dsid` would be assigned a value of 1.  The second time it would be assigned a value of 2.  If you then run a `close()` the '2' would be closed, but the '1' would still be open.  No matter how many times you then ran an `open()` and `close()` the '1' would never be closed unless you manually ran `close(1)` which is effectively what my code snippet above is doing.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation robert. U were right, code errored out before it encountered Close().

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error today when trying to re-assign a library. Looking back through my log I saw the following (after a proc append):

```
NOTE: BASE file MYLIB.MYDS.DATA set to record level control because there is at 
least one other open of this file. The append process may take longer to complete.
```

Running Robert's macro (close_all_dsid) fixed it.  The OS was Windows 2008r2 running SAS 9.2 in a Stored Process server session.  The append was successful. Will be back if / when I figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can kill and restart the session, and then it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

please add the following code at the beginning of the code:

```
ods path reset;
```